# Assembly CMP result differs depending on used register?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, cmp

I've been working on my assembly project and came across a fact I can't understand.

I have a word-array called "lent" filled with some numbers. When I print what is under 0 index it shows ASCII 0 (NULL). However, when I use CMP to check if the value is 0, I get some trouble. Here is some code:

```
mov di,offset lent
mov cx,0d
cmp ds:[di],cx
```

It returns not equal, as if [di] did not contain zero.
However:

```
mov di,offset lent
mov cl,0d
cmp ds:[di],cl
```

returns equal, and there makes me confused. I need the first case to be working in my code.
If it is a lame question, I am sorry, but I was not able to find an appropriate answer on the Internet. Thanks in advance

Comment: _"When I print what is under 0 index it shows ASCII 0 (NULL)."_   Are you printing the whole word or just the lower byte?

Comment: I did it like this:
`mov dx,ds:[di]
mov ah,2d
int 21h`

Comment: That would only print a single character (from `DL`, i.e. the lower byte).

Comment: To be more specific: I need `ds:[lent]` to equal `offset tab`, and in the code it is like:
`mov di,offset tab | mov bx,offset lent | mov ds:[bx],di` and it does not work.

Comment: Could you show the whole section of your code where you both store the value and then try to compare against it? (rather than just one part or the other)

Comment: `cmp ds:[di],cx` compares CX (16 bits) to the 16 bits found at ds:[di], while `cmp ds:[di],cl` compares the lower 1/2 of CX (CL - 8 bits) to the 8 bits of data found at ds:[di]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sparky's answer is correct. 
To avoid confusion and to detect bugs, try to use size prefixes like

```
mov di, offset lent
mov cl, 0d
cmp byte ptr [di], cl
```

if you try to use the word ptr prefix, like

```
cmp word ptr [di], cl
```

using debug.exe, it will show you an error msg.

Answer (score 2):

The second case is comparing one byte of  against one byte in .  This byte matches (ZF=1).

However, the first case is actually comparing two bytes of  against the two bytes in .  Only one of the two bytes match.  Hence, you get ZF=0.

Answer (score 0):

mov ds:[di] to a register and have a look at it

mov di,offset lent

mov cx,0d

cmp ds:[di],cx

becomes:

mov di,offset lent

mov cx,0d

mov ax,[di]

cmp al,cl

cmp ax,cx

cmp ah,ch

to have a look-see and debug it kinda thing

Comment: I got it working, in spite of not fully understanding why.
I replaced moving 16-bits variable (containing offset) to a 16-bit register (no longer `mov si,ds:[lent]`) with moving byte ptr to such a variable into an 8-bit half-register, so it's now 
`mov bl,byte ptr ds:[di]` (that's after `xor bx,bx` to ensure the high part is empty as well). I struggle to understand this...